# Animating content in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to animate a couple of Composables between 2 states, basically change from a `Row` to a `Column`. In the view system I would place these in a `ConstraintLayout` and then update the constraints based on the layout I want to use - what would be the equivalent way to do this on Jetpack Compose? I can also define a `ConstraintLayout`, but I'm interested in a solution that does not depend on that.

This is what I tried, but it does not animate the view positions, it just fades one out and fades the other in instead. I understand that there has to be some connection between the 2 composables in each state so that they can be animated, but I don't know how to achieve that.

```
enum class ContentState {
    One,
    Two,
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Composable
fun ContentAnimator(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    state: ContentState = ContentState.One,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
    ) {
        AnimatedContent(
            targetState = state,
        ) { targetState ->
            when (targetState) {
                ContentState.One -> OneLayout()
                ContentState.Two -> TwoLayout()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun OneLayout() {
    Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = 48.dp, height = 48.dp)
                .background(Color.Red),
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Sample text",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun TwoLayout() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(width = 48.dp, height = 48.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Sample text",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
        )
    }
}
```

I want to go back and forth between these 2 states shown below. I presume another option would be to use a `Layout` and an `animatable` object and then manually compute the position of the 2 objects based on the `animatable`, but that seems like a very low level solution.

[image: From]

[image: To]

Comment: To animate an object, it has to be exactly the same object in the Compose tree, and in your code you create different views for different layouts. The `ConstraintLayout' works because by changing the constraints you are moving the same views, not creating new ones. See [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/): it talks about a different declarative UI framework, but in Compose it works exactly the same way for the same reasons.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that, but is there a way other than using a ConstraintLayout or manually moving the views in a Layout? That's what I'm asking.

Comment: @Philip, I think I'd like to disagree with that. [Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation#animatedcontent) is an example using two different views but it works just fine if you define a custom transitionSpec. Just scroll down a bit in the section where they are explaining the `SizeTransform` (Composable?)

Comment: Oh it's Composables not Views

Comment: `AnimatedContent` was the first place my mind went to as well, but I think it is kinda unnecessary to use these APIs when you don't have to. Why can't you just use the animateDpAsState to animate the Offset in a custom Composable? `AnimatedContent` does not support individually animating the child composables so it is kinda complicated to make it work. Give the other approach a try, or just let us know if you need some sample or something

Comment: This was a simplified scenario, in my actual case I have more than just 2 views.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a stupendously simple implementation, but it works like a charm. Also, no `ConstraintLayout`.

```
@Composable
fun Sample(state: AlignmentState){
    //Dimensions of the static/stable box
    val redWidth = 50
    val redHeight = 50
    
    //Animated Coordinates of the dynamic box
    val blueX by animateDpAsState(targetValue = (if (state == AlignmentState.Rowed) (redWidth * 1.25f).roundToInt() else 0).dp )
    val blueY by animateDpAsState(targetValue = (if (state == AlignmentState.Rowed) 0 else redHeight).dp)
    
    Layout(content = {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(redWidth.dp)
                .width(redHeight.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(50.dp)
                .width(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
        )
    }) { measurables, constraints ->
        val red = measurables[0].measure(constraints)
        val blue = measurables[1].measure(constraints)
        
        layout(constraints.maxWidth, constraints.maxHeight) {
            red.place(0, 0)
            blue.place(blueX.value.roundToInt(), blueY.value.roundToInt())
        }
        
    }

}
```

You might want to swap out `animateDpAsState` with `animateIntAsState` to avoid all the boilerplate above. Anyway, this assumes that you know the dimensions of s=fixed box, but you know, just alter it per your use case.

Comment: You would not have a problem creating the `AlignmentState` enum so I skipped it